# Cannot bind object to view using Caliburn - UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, caliburn.micro, uwp-xaml

I am trying to bind an object using Caliburn, and use some of its properties (ReferredBy, in this case) for taking input. I can't seem to do it, here is my code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Sponsor}" Margin="20">
<TextBlock Text="Referred By" />
<TextBox Name="ReferredBy" Width="100" Height="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Sponsor is an object in the corresponding ViewModel,

```
 public Sponsor Sponsor { get; private set; }
```

Aso, Sponsor is initialized on page load. I can access any other variable I declare in viewmodel by Caliburn's naming convention but not this model. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind nested properties with the following convention:

```
<TextBox Name="Sponsor_ReferredBy" Width="100" Height="20"/>
```

This way you won't need to bind `Sponsor` to the enclosing StackPanel.

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver!